# Custom CSS Based on ID with appendTo('head')

Tags: jquery, css

So I am working on a Chrome/Firefox extension that will look for a specific element and extract the innerHTML within it. After that, I need to style it and make the background red. The part that I am struggling with is getting the background color to change to red whenever such element has data in it based on its id. I am using appendTo('head') for the css.

```
var message = $(node).find('span.mention.style-scope.yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer');
if (message.length < 1) return;
var messageID = $('.style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer').attr('id');
$('<style type="text/css">.style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer #id' + messageID + ' { background-color: #FF0000; }</style>').appendTo('head');
```

The last line is the issue. I have used this code before, but have not attached an id on it, so I am not sure where to go from here on.

Any pointers would be great, and if you need more information, I can do my best to provide you with it. Thanks!

EDIT:

This is what I am trying to target:

```
<yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer class="style-scope yt-live-chat-item-list-renderer x-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer-0" id="CjkKGkNLYlR2dUNlNjlNQ0ZVT3ZxZ29kR2FrS3ZREhtDTDdxejlxZTY5TUNGY25YbkFvZGR2a0JjdzA%3D" author-type="">
```

Comment: Are you trying to add css content dynamically to `<head>`? If so, why?

Comment: Yes. It is meant to overwrite what is displayed on YouTube and this is what has been working so far. I just haven't gotten it to work when I want to focus on just an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#id' + messageID + '` is actually rendering as `#id<messageId>` instead of `#<messageId>`

You are missing class identifier `.` next to `yt-..` so css cannot find that element.

Also,
You can just use ID to refer that element, no need to add any other class like `.style-scope .yt-live-chat-item-list...` as the ID is unique for a page.

It is a very bad practice to add something like this to head.

Comment: I changed it to `$('<style type="text/css">#' + messageID + ' { background-color: #FF0000; }</style>').appendTo('head');` but still no luck.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1  if answers are not working  then why you accepted it?

Answer (score 0):

remove **#id+messageID**  and used #+messageID. please refer the code below:

```
$('<style type="text/css">.style-scope yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer #' + messageID + ' { background-color: #FF0000; }</style>').appendTo('head');
```

Your code contains % symbol due to which CSS compiler is not able to find the selector

Comment: why try? any reason? A good answer must have some explanation

Comment: Respectful that was. thanks @AlivetoDie will remember moving forward

Comment: @RockGuitarist1: remove % symbol from the ID everywhere